# How to read end of log file using batch command?

Tags: java, windows, file, batch-file

I am new to batch commands. How to read end of log file?
I have many operations in my batch file, I just want a synchronous way of operations.

One of the operation is java silent installation, I need to do another operation after java is getting installed. Since it's silent installation, it doesn't showing up it's completion.
Therefore am writing the details into log file just to identify, java is installed or not.
Just to start up the next process, I should confirm that java is installed.

Parallel log file reading is possible upon installing? or any other solution?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, if you want to read the last line of a .txt log file, this is a way of doing it:

#### Save as ".bat" file

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set /a linecount=0
set /a linecheck=0
set target=logfile.txt

for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (%target%) do (
set /a linecount=!linecount!+1
)
for /f "tokens=*" %%x in (%target% do (
set /a linecheck=!linecheck!+1
if !linecheck! equ !linecount! (
Echo Last line is: %%x
Rem Add whatever you want to do to your last line refering to it as %%x
)
)
```

Where logfile.txt will be replaced with your file name.

You can call this script a number of times if you want to do it to more then one log file

Hope this helped

Yours, Mona